Use sqoop to import oracle data to hive. Although sqoop reports an error, hive can find the data
hadoop version is 3.3.3
hive version is 3.1.0
sqoop version is 1.4.7
Use sqoop to import oracle data to hive. Although sqoop reports an error, hive can find the data
I executed the following script as user root
bin/sqoop import \
    --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:1521:orcl \
    --username ***\
    --password *** \
    --query "select * from XLSB.GG where \$CONDITIONS" \
    --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/ddp_hive_test.db \
    --hive-import \
    --hive-database ddp_hive_test\
    --hive-table GG \
    --delete-target-dir \
    --outdir /tmp \
    -m 1

I'll put in my error message below
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Exception thrown when executing query : SELECT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTableColumnStatistics' AS `NUCLEUS_TYPE`,`A0`.`AVG_COL_LEN`,`A0`.`CAT_NAME`,`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME`,`A0`.`COLUMN_TYPE`,`A0`.`DB_NAME`,`A0`.`BIG_DECIMAL_HIGH_VALUE`,`A0`.`BIG_DECIMAL_LOW_VALUE`,`A0`.`DOUBLE_HIGH_VALUE`,`A0`.`DOUBLE_LOW_VALUE`,`A0`.`LAST_ANALYZED`,`A0`.`LONG_HIGH_VALUE`,`A0`.`LONG_LOW_VALUE`,`A0`.`MAX_COL_LEN`,`A0`.`NUM_DISTINCTS`,`A0`.`NUM_FALSES`,`A0`.`NUM_NULLS`,`A0`.`NUM_TRUES`,`A0`.`TABLE_NAME`,`A0`.`CS_ID` FROM `TAB_COL_STATS` `A0` WHERE `A0`.`TABLE_NAME` = ? AND `A0`.`DB_NAME` = ? AND `A0`.`CAT_NAME` = ? AND ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)))
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.setPartitionColumnStatistics(Hive.java:4423)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.stats.ColStatsProcessor.persistColumnStats(ColStatsProcessor.java:179)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.stats.ColStatsProcessor.process(ColStatsProcessor.java:83)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.StatsTask.execute(StatsTask.java:108)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:205)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:97)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2664)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:2335)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:2011)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1709)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1703)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:157)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:218)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:239)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:188)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:402)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:335)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:471)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:487)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:793)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport: Caused by: MetaException(message:Exception thrown when executing query : SELECT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTableColumnStatistics' AS `NUCLEUS_TYPE`,`A0`.`AVG_COL_LEN`,`A0`.`CAT_NAME`,`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME`,`A0`.`COLUMN_TYPE`,`A0`.`DB_NAME`,`A0`.`BIG_DECIMAL_HIGH_VALUE`,`A0`.`BIG_DECIMAL_LOW_VALUE`,`A0`.`DOUBLE_HIGH_VALUE`,`A0`.`DOUBLE_LOW_VALUE`,`A0`.`LAST_ANALYZED`,`A0`.`LONG_HIGH_VALUE`,`A0`.`LONG_LOW_VALUE`,`A0`.`MAX_COL_LEN`,`A0`.`NUM_DISTINCTS`,`A0`.`NUM_FALSES`,`A0`.`NUM_NULLS`,`A0`.`NUM_TRUES`,`A0`.`TABLE_NAME`,`A0`.`CS_ID` FROM `TAB_COL_STATS` `A0` WHERE `A0`.`TABLE_NAME` = ? AND `A0`.`DB_NAME` = ? AND `A0`.`CAT_NAME` = ? AND ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)) OR (`A0`.`COLUMN_NAME` = ?)))
2024-05-27 02:05:03,378 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$set_aggr_stats_for_result$set_aggr_stats_for_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$set_aggr_stats_for_result$set_aggr_stats_for_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$set_aggr_stats_for_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_set_aggr_stats_for(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:4104)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.set_aggr_stats_for(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:4091)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.setPartitionColumnStatistics(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1927)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.setPartitionColumnStatistics(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:409)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:212)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.setPartitionColumnStatistics(Unknown Source)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2773)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.setPartitionColumnStatistics(Unknown Source)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.setPartitionColumnStatistics(Hive.java:4420)
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport:   ... 27 more
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  ReOptimizePlugin:70 - ReOptimization: retryPossible: false
2024-05-27 02:05:03,380 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 ERROR Driver:1247 - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.StatsTask
2024-05-27 02:05:03,381 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  Driver:1224 - MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
2024-05-27 02:05:03,381 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  Driver:1224 - Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 13.97 sec   HDFS Read: 1870859 HDFS Write: 1825605 SUCCESS
2024-05-27 02:05:03,381 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  Driver:1224 - Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 13 seconds 970 msec
2024-05-27 02:05:03,381 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  Driver:2531 - Completed executing command(queryId=root_20240527020415_6f8493db-8d4b-4383-89c2-6e34b1a87e09); Time taken: 45.907 seconds
2024-05-27 02:05:03,381 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  Driver:285 - Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
2024-05-27 02:05:03,384 INFO hive.HiveImport: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.StatsTask
2024-05-27 02:05:03,390 INFO hive.HiveImport: MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
2024-05-27 02:05:03,390 INFO hive.HiveImport: Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 13.97 sec   HDFS Read: 1870859 HDFS Write: 1825605 SUCCESS
2024-05-27 02:05:03,390 INFO hive.HiveImport: Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 13 seconds 970 msec
2024-05-27 02:05:03,438 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  HiveConf:5034 - Using the default value passed in for log id: 440599c2-e482-4bde-afab-9f9c570043d8
2024-05-27 02:05:03,438 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  SessionState:449 - Resetting thread name to  main
2024-05-27 02:05:03,438 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  HiveConf:5034 - Using the default value passed in for log id: 440599c2-e482-4bde-afab-9f9c570043d8
2024-05-27 02:05:03,472 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  SessionState:882 - Deleted directory: /tmp/hive/root/440599c2-e482-4bde-afab-9f9c570043d8 on fs with scheme hdfs
2024-05-27 02:05:03,473 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  SessionState:882 - Deleted directory: /tmp/root/440599c2-e482-4bde-afab-9f9c570043d8 on fs with scheme file
2024-05-27 02:05:03,473 INFO hive.HiveImport: 2024-05-27 02:05:03 INFO  HiveMetaStoreClient:600 - Closed a connection to metastore, current connections: 1
2024-05-27 02:05:03,964 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 1
        at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:384)
        at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:337)
        at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:241)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:537)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:81)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)

But a different error occurred when I switched to hdfs or hive to execute the script
2024-05-27 02:18:43,815 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
2024-05-27 02:18:43,815 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
2024-05-27 02:18:43,816 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: It seems that you're doing hive import directly into default
2024-05-27 02:18:43,816 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: hive warehouse directory which is not supported. Sqoop is
2024-05-27 02:18:43,816 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: firstly importing data into separate directory and then
2024-05-27 02:18:43,816 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: inserting data into hive. Please consider removing
2024-05-27 02:18:43,816 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: --target-dir or --warehouse-dir into /user/hive/warehouse in
2024-05-27 02:18:43,816 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: case that you will detect any issues.
2024-05-27 02:18:43,982 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
2024-05-27 02:18:44,009 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
2024-05-27 02:18:44,014 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
2024-05-27 02:18:44,821 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
2024-05-27 02:18:44,926 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select * from XLSB.GG where  (1 = 0) 
2024-05-27 02:18:44,955 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select * from XLSB.GG where  (1 = 0) 
2024-05-27 02:18:45,062 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/datasophon/hadoop-3.3.3
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hive/compile/a83bac474f62d660ae95b9693ece74f0/QueryResult.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2024-05-27 02:18:48,931 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hive/compile/a83bac474f62d660ae95b9693ece74f0/QueryResult.jar
2024-05-27 02:18:50,964 INFO tool.ImportTool: Destination directory /user/hive/warehouse/ddp_hive_test.db deleted.
2024-05-27 02:18:50,968 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning query import.
2024-05-27 02:18:50,969 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2024-05-27 02:18:50,983 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
2024-05-27 02:18:51,010 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
2024-05-27 02:18:51,212 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: Loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2024-05-27 02:18:51,253 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2024-05-27 02:18:51,253 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system started
2024-05-27 02:18:52,101 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop/mapred/staging/hive1937623722/.staging/job_local1937623722_0001
2024-05-27 02:18:52,105 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: ENOENT: No such file or directory
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:382)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:974)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:572)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:752)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.mkdirs(JobResourceUploader.java:660)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadResourcesInternal(JobResourceUploader.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadResources(JobResourceUploader.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1568)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1568)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1589)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:200)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:270)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importQuery(SqlManager.java:748)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:522)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:81)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)

I don't know how to solve it
I am a big data field white, the previous big data cluster only used the root user, but when I used some automation tools to help me deploy hadoop cluster, I created a lot of users, so far, root and hive have been added to the supergrop and hive group. I don't know whether the problem is related to user permission or other reasons. I hope to get help from friends in the community, thank you
